# Connecting dots on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, illustrator-scripting

Is that possible to connect dots in Adobe Illustrator, automatically?

To do something like this:

[image]

Comment: be warned that this illustration is *not* eacht point connected to each other. It looks like each point is only connected to 4-6 of its closest neighbours, and not all lines are straight.

Comment: Looks like it was created in a 3D app to me. Possibly a sphere primitive with crumple effect applied. Much easier than drawing manually in Illustrator!

Comment: @MarcEdwards Crumple effect? This looks loke a folded effect. Can you give us an example?

Comment: I think this is just a photo...

Answer (score 4):

[image]

> **All Points v.1.3** This script simply draws a line from every point to every other point of your selected pathitem. Handy for making
>   Mandalas. Try on polygons, stars or even freehand shapes.

From: http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/

Comment: This script is not working

Comment: It was a year ago wehen this question was asked. But your problem description is certainly no help in clearing it up either.