# How to get a script to connect all points in Illustrator working?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, automation, illustrator-scripting

How can I get this script 'to connect all the corner points of a path by straight lines' working?

I downloaded a script called 'All Points' from here but it is not working: http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/

To explain further: if I have a square, I can just connect the diagonally opposite points to create diagonal lines. This gets very complex when dealing with shapes with a large number of points as exemplified here:
http://js4ai.blogspot.in/2009/05/spoze-you-have-shape-like-this-and-you.html

The script shows an error, after I select a polygon and run it:

> Error 8705: Target layer cannot be modified
>
> Line: 195
>
> var shapeGroup = app.activeDocument.groupItems.add();

PS: The script also finds a mention in the answer to this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49311/connecting-dots-on-illustrator).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting dots on Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49311/connecting-dots-on-illustrator)

Comment: @Luciano It is a build of that question as that script is now showing error, maybe someone knows how to fix that error. Let me know id I need to edit my question more.

Comment: You're asking tech support about a script already posted in an answer to another question. Have you tried contacting the script author or the answerer on the other question? Did you explain _what_ is not working?

Comment: @Luciano Yes, I have contacted the author, no response yet. Good point, I will post what is not working here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, the layer can't be modified, which means the selected layer is either hidden or locked. Be aware that the active *layer* is not the same as the layer of the object[s] you have selected. The active layer is the layer that is highlighted in the layers panel.

As you can see here, the object selected is on "Layer 1", the selected *layer* is "Layer 2". Since that layer is hidden, if you run the script now you get the error "Target layer cannot be modified":

[image: Active layer hidden]

Make sure the layer is visible and the script works as expected:

[image: Active layer visible]

Comment: Ah that worked. Thanks a lot! I am surprised I missed that :)